# Android Studio: How to detect a quick tap on the screen

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm making a Tetris game. I'm still at the start and I ran into this problem. I need a way to sensor a QUICK tap on the screen. A  "finger down" and  a fast "finger up" following that. I tried using ACTION_DOWN but it feels any touch on screen, no matter what happens next.
Can anyone please help me sensor that quick tap? Thank you in advance.